# Insert multiple values to the same database column from HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have created complex form, I'll try to provide simplified examples. There are ability to generate more fields by clicking `+` button.

For example in form are fields:

```
Certificate    Date Of Issue    Date of Expire   
[         ]    [           ]    [            ]   +
```

by clicking `+` button It add duplicate row (via javascript) so after clicking `+` button part of form looks like:

```
Certificate    Date Of Issue    Date of Expire   
[         ]    [           ]    [            ]

Certificate    Date Of Issue    Date of Expire  
[         ]    [           ]    [            ]   +
```

There are ability to click `+` button as many times as user needs.

In database table `CV_Certificates` I have columns `CertificateId`, `CertDateofIssue`, `CertDateOfExpire`

I'm using `insert.php` to insert values to database in following:

```
$Certificate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Certificate']);             
$CertDateOfIssue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CertDateOfIssue']);             
$CertDateOfExpire = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CertDateOfExpire']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO CV_Certificates (Certificate, CertDateOfIssue, CertDateOfExpire) VALUES ('$Certificate','$CertDateOfIssue','$CertDateOfExpire')

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Resume created successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

It inserting values only from 1 row, but It should insert values from all added rows to multiple database table's rows.

---

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
<legend>5. Certificates</legend>

<ul class="Certificates" id="Certificates"> 
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="Certificate">Certificate Name</label>
                <input id="Certificate" type="text" name="Certificate" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Certificate" />    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="CertDateOfIssue">Date of Issue</label>
                <input id="CertDateOfIssue" type="date" name="CertDateOfIssue" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Issue" />  
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="column">         
            <li>
                <label for="CertDateOfExpire">Date of Expire</label>
                <input id="CertDateOfExpire" type="date" name="CertDateOfExpire" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Expire" />   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>   
<ul class="Certificates1"></ul>
<button type="button" class="add-row1">+</button> 

</fieldset>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".add-row1" ).click(function(){
      $( "ul.Certificates" ).first().clone().appendTo( ".Certificates1" ).append('<button class="remove">X</button>').find('input').val("");
   });
   $( "body" ).on('click', '.remove', function(){
    $(this).closest('.Certificates').remove();
  });
});
```

How could I achieve It? Also as I noticed, this is extremely simplified form, there are over 150 fields at all.

**UPDATE**

This is real part from my code which return an error: `ERROR: Could not able to execute .` And not inserting values to database at all now.

```
foreach($SeaService as $key=>$res) {

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO CV_SeaServices (
UserId
,NameOfVessel           
,TypeOfVessel           
,YearBuilt              
,Flag                   
,DWT                    
,TypeOfMEkW             
,SSRankApplied          
,SignOn                 
,SignOff                
,CompanyName            
) VALUES (
'$res',
'$NameOfVessel[$key]',      
'$TypeOfVessel[$key]',      
'$YearBuilt[$key]',             
'$Flag[$key]',              
'$DWT[$key]',               
'$TypeOfMEkW[$key]',        
'$SSRankApplied[$key]',         
'$SignOn[$key]',            
'$SignOff[$key]',           
'$CompanyName[$key]')";

};
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
    echo "Resume created successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: You can add as many groups to your `VALUES` clause as you would like e.g., `VALUES ('stuff')('more stuff, same columns')('yet more stuff, same column')` as long as the column counts match in each group. You will have to loop through the array you post to create each additional group.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you for your suggestion, but It a bit is not clear for me, how correctly use this `stuff`...

Comment: Each `()` contains the information you wish to insert in a row.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you for trying to explain, but It still not clear for me, I know how It's working `VALUES (val1,val2,valn), (val1-2, val2-2,valn-2), etc`, but can't understand how can I make It dynamically... If user will click `+` button like 100 times, to add 100 certificates, should I provide `()` 100 times? But If 101 time It will break again, there is no any dynamic way?

Comment: you should use array of form elements by adding Certificate[],CertDateOfIssue[],CertDateOfExpire[]

Answer (score 1):

Each input addition must have a new name, or the variable must be an array:

```
<input id="Certificate" type="date" name="Certificate[]" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Expire" />`

<input id="CertDateOfIssue" type="date" name="CertDateOfIssue[]" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Issue" /> `

<input id="CertDateOfIssue" type="date" name="CertDateOfIssue[]" class="field-style field-split25 align-left" placeholder="Date of Issue" />`
```

Now in your PHP

```
$certificate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Certificate']);          
$certDateOfIssue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CertDateOfIssue']);             
$certDateOfExpire = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['CertDateOfExpire']);

foreach($certificate as $key=>$res) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO CV_Certificates (Certificate, CertDateOfIssue, CertDateOfExpire) VALUES ('$res','$certDateOfIssue[$key]','$certDateOfExpire[$key]')
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
foreach($SeaService as $key=>$res) {

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO CV_SeaServices (
UserId
,NameOfVessel           
,TypeOfVessel           
,YearBuilt              
,Flag                   
,DWT                    
,TypeOfMEkW             
,SSRankApplied          
,SignOn                 
,SignOff                
,CompanyName            
) VALUES (
'$res',
'$NameOfVessel[$key]',      
'$TypeOfVessel[$key]',      
'$YearBuilt[$key]',             
'$Flag[$key]',              
'$DWT[$key]',               
'$TypeOfMEkW[$key]',        
'$SSRankApplied[$key]',         
'$SignOn[$key]',            
'$SignOff[$key]',           
'$CompanyName[$key]')";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
    echo "Resume created successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do individual insert statements when you can create one?

Comment: Sure, it is one. I was just curious. Seems like a lot of queries to issue all at once.

Comment: @santosh thank you for an answer, but this error gives me an error, check my updated question.

Comment: @santosh I've tried It, but for now I don't get any message at all (blank screen) and data still not inserting to database...

Comment: data is not inserting into database ?? could you please dump $SeaService

Comment: After using `var_dump($SeaService);` It returning  `NULL`

Comment: nothing is posting this is the reason .. you insert query is not working

Comment: @santosh have you ideas why it happening?

Comment: @Infinity $SeaService  there is no value ..
if you could post that form and method i could look on in.